# What's the length of the segment $HN$ in the figure below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the drawing, $T$ is the point of tangency, $LN || AT$, $OH = 4$ and $LN^2+AM^2=164$.
Calculate $HN$. (Answer: $8$)

*Both circles have the same radius.

[image]

Progress:

By [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem), $\triangle LNT-NH \implies LN^2+NT^2=2(HN^2+HT^2)$,
but $HT=OH=4$, therefore $LN^2+NT^2=2(HN^2+16)...$.

Comment: What is TH. Stewart?

Comment: @Gary  Stewart's theorem   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem

Comment: @petaarantes The drawing contradicts the fact that radiuses are equal. LO' is obviously less than OT. And drawing shows that AHN is not straight line.

Comment: If we exclude equal radiuses requirement and the fact that AHN is straight line, problem can be solved and HN is about 8.16. AX is diameter then ABX is 90°, CBX=CYX=LYA=90°. Then one can show that AL=AT and H is middle of LT.

Answer (score 1):

Comment

With given values $NH\neq 8$ and if $NH=8$ , $OH=4$ and $LN^2+AM^2=164$ then the figure can not be constructed. What I could construct is:

-Radius of circles $r=5.5$

-$LN=8.94$, $AM=8.9$ $\Rightarrow LN^2+AM^2=158$

-$LH=OH=4$

which gives : $HN^2=8,9^2-4^2=8$

-$\angle AMN=90^o$

-$NM=10.5$

-These measures  give $AN=13.8$

You have to show these measure by calculation.

Comment: thanks ..Probably error in the statement